# Python Floats to 32 bit limited number

Tags: python, python-3.x

As seen on this webiste: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

I have looked through five or so posts on stack overflow but they are not quite what I am looking for. For example:

```
import struct

getBin = lambda x: x > 0 and str(bin(x))[2:] or "-" + str(bin(x))[3:]

def floatToBinary64(value):
    val = struct.unpack('Q', struct.pack('d', value))[0]
    return getBin(val)

def binaryToFloat(value):
    hx = hex(int(value, 2))   
    return struct.unpack("d", struct.pack("q", int(hx, 16)))[0]

# floats are represented by IEEE 754 floating-point format which are 
# 64 bits long (not 32 bits)

# float to binary
binstr = floatToBinary64(NUMBER)
print('Binary equivalent of .1:')
print(binstr + '\n')

# binary to float
fl = binaryToFloat(binstr)
print('Decimal equivalent of ' + binstr)
print(fl)
```

I realize that this is pretty close to what I'm looking for. If you put .1 into this code where number is, it lists it as .1 while on the website it gives me: 0.10000000149011612.

If anyone can help that would be great!

Comment: What website gives you that answer? EDIT: Sorry it's right at the top...duh

Comment: Why does the title say 32?

Comment: I'm still confused about the question though...So the website says 32 bit floats, python uses 64 bits floats, and you are confused as to why the values are different?

Comment: I'm trying to write in python what the website has written in javascript. In my understanding the 64 bit numbers are where .1 can equal .1 but in 32 bit .1 is equal to something like .1000000002 or something. I'm writing a program that involves this. I think the code I put in the question is 64 bit code not 32 bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just because Python shows you the nicest representation of that number. The value actually is exactly this:

```
>>> '%.60f' % fl
'0.100000000000000005551115123125782702118158340454101562500000'
```

Which is exactly what the literal `0.1` turns into:

```
>>> '%.60f' % 0.1
'0.100000000000000005551115123125782702118158340454101562500000'
```

(Oh and it's not 0.10000000149011612 because that's done with 32 instead of 64 bits. And actually that one should be 0.100000001490116119384765625, that converter page is inaccurate.)

Comment: Oh that makes more sense! Although, on the website .1 is 0.10000000149011612 not 0.10000000000000000555 have any ideas why that is?

Comment: @AndersonP See my comment at the end or BretD's comment above.

Comment: Is there anyway to simulate 32 bit in python or can it only use 64? Thank you for your help

Comment: I see there may be a 32 bit mask: 0xffffffff I'll figure out how to use it

Comment: @AndersonP Not sure about losses during the multiple conversions, but `'%.60f' % ctypes.c_float(fl).value` does give me `0.100000001490116119384765625000000000000000000000000000000000`. That converter page's author doesn't know what he's doing, `0.10000000149011612` isn't the actual value.

Comment: @AndersonP To clarify: I meant not sure about losses in general. In this particular case I know that the end result is correct (as confirmed in C++ with `printf("%.60f", 0.1f)` and also by casevh's answer). But for other cases the `literal`-to-`float`-to-`c_float`-to-`float` conversion path I could imagine ending up with something "wrong", due to the losses in the first two steps.

Comment: Where did you get ctypes.c_float(f1) from? It says ctypes is undefined

Comment: @AndersonP Well `import ctypes`.

Comment: That works! How do I select this comment as the answer? Or are you able to put it in the codeblock?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [gmpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2) library to work with arbitrary precision binary numbers, including the standard 32-bit and 64-bit IEEE formats.

Here is an example:

```
>>> import gmpy2
>>> gmpy2.set_context(gmpy2.ieee(64))
>>> gmpy2.mpfr("0.1").__format__(".60f")
'0.100000000000000005551115123125782702118158340454101562500000'
>>> gmpy2.set_context(gmpy2.ieee(32))
>>> gmpy2.mpfr("0.1").__format__(".60f")
'0.100000001490116119384765625000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

**Edit: Added example function to convert mpfr to 32-bit IEEE format.**

```
import gmpy2
gmpy2.set_context(gmpy2.ieee(32))

def mpfr_to_float(x):
    '''Convert an mpfr object created by the IEEE 32-bit compatible
    context to a 32 character string containing 0 and 1.'''

    # Check for special values first.

    if gmpy2.is_infinite(x):
        if gmpy2.is_signed(x):
            return "1" * 9 + "0" * 23
        else:
            return "0" + "1" * 8 + "0" * 23

    if gmpy2.is_nan(x):
        return "0" + "1" * 31

    if gmpy2.is_zero(x):
        if gmpy2.is_signed(x):
            return "1" + "0" * 31
        else:
            return "0" * 32

    # Extract the mantissa, exponent, and precision. Note that the
    # values are slightly different than the IEEE 32-bit standard.

    mnt, exp, prc = x.digits(2)

    # MPFR explicitely stores the leading bit of the mantissa so the
    # precision is 24. To support subnormals, MPFR also uses a more
    # negative minimum exponent and decreases the precision of the
    # mantissa but maintains the leading '1' bit.

    # Remove any leading sign bit from the mantissa string.
    if mnt[0] == "-":
        sign_char = "1"
        mnt = mnt[1:]
    else:
        sign_char = "0"

    # Check for subnormals
    if exp + 126 <= 0:
        # Drop the last bit since it will always be '0' and after the
        # adjustments for subnormals, the leading bit will be '0'.
        mnt = mnt[:-1]
    else:
        # Drop the leading '1' bit for normal numbers.
        mnt = mnt[1:]

    # Handle subnormals by shifting trailing bits from the mantissa
    # string to the beginning. Adjust the exponent to match.
    while exp + 126 < 0:
        mnt = mnt[-1] + mnt[:-1]
        exp = exp + 1

    # Adjust the exponent to account for removing a bit from the
    # mantissa string.
    exp = exp - 1

    # Add 127 to the exponent to account for the IEEE encoding.
    exp = exp + 127

    # Validate exponent range.
    if (exp > 255) or (exp < 0):
        raise ValueError("exp is out of bounds")

    # Build and return the binary string.
    result = sign_char + format(exp, "08b") + mnt
    if len(result) != 32:
        raise ValueError("something is wrong....")

    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(mpfr_to_float(gmpy2.mpfr("0.1")))
```

Disclaimer #1: This should really be a comment to @Stefan Pochmann's answer but I thought a code example would be helpful.

Disclaimer #2: I maintain gmpy2.

Comment: Less instructive than going through the representation with `struct.pack`/`struct.unpack` on our own, but certainly simpler/nicer/safer to use. And better than my `ctypes.c_float(0.1).value` hack. Just one question: Does gmpy2 offer showing the bits of the IEEE representation (as done on that web page and by the OP's code)?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Unfortunately not. The underlying MPFR library uses a different internal representation. MPFR does provide functions to convert to IEEE float and double values but I don't expose the float version since Python doesn't provide a native 32-bit floating point type. I will try to write a Python mpfr-to-float converter and edit my answer.

Comment: Oh wow, really shows that you're doing this stuff seriously :-)

Comment: This is very helpful and looks like it will be just what I need! I have two questions. 1: How do I install this? Never done that before but just doing import gmpy2 doesn't work so I assume I need to install something (not sure which file to use from your link). 2: is there a way to put a variable where the .1 is? for example if I have the user input which number they wish to be converted how would that look? Thanks again!

Comment: Also, how do I install this on python 3.6? When I use the .exe it says only python 2.7

Comment: Python extensions are generally distributed as `wheels` (files with a `.whl` file extension). They are installed using a program called `pip`. I am currently not able to build wheels for Python 3.5 or 3.6 but they are available from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ My apologies that the PyPi site is a little out-of-date. I'm working on an update.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense! Thanks